# Server-side rendering with react-router is not working

Tags: react-router

I'm using express, and I want to do some basic routing server-side.  At the moment I'm just trying to set up the router to do *anything*.  Right now it always returns a 404.

I believe I've followed the directions listed on https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md.

It's about as basic as you can get: an express server that routes every request to be handled by the code from the link listed above, and a ReactRouter that routes everything to the AppTemplate component.

It's definitely getting to the callback in routes.js, because it returns 'Not found' for every request.

I doubt it matters, but I'm running it in IIS via iisnode.  I've been having troubles debugging, which is one of the reasons I'm switching from express-react-views to routing via the `<Router>`.

Let me know what other information i can get you.

#### File structure:

```
server/
-- server.js // just calls babel-register and express-app.js
-- express-app.js
-- router.js

server/views/
-- app-template.js
-- routes.js
```

#### server/express-app.js

```
import Express from 'express';
import BodyParser from 'body-parser';
import CookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

let app = new Express();
export default app;

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.use('/public', Express.static('../dist'));

app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(CookieParser());

// some rest API code here, currently commented out

app.set('tokenSecret', process.env.tokenSecret);

require('./router');
```

#### server/router.js

```
// copied right from https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md.
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext} from 'react-router';

import app from './express-app';
import Routes from './views/routes';

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    match({ Routes, location: req.originalUrl }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
            res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
        } else if (renderProps) {
            res.status(200).send(renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />));
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Not found');
        }
    });
});
```

#### server/views/routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';

import AppTemplate from './app-template';

export default (
    <Router>
        <Route path='/' component={AppTemplate}>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

#### server/views/app-template.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class AppTemplate extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id='app' />
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble with this a few weeks ago but somehow got it working, here are a few things I did differently that may or may not affect your implementation:

1. rather than using express.get, I used express.use with no path specification, meaning react-router acts more like middleware than a request handler.
2. in the first argument to match, my object key is "routes" rather than "Routes"
3. I'm using the 'history' module as well, so my location is created using createLocation(req.originalUrl) - createLocation comes from 'history'.

Try giving this stuff a shot, otherwise I can also post an adapted version of my code.

#### Note from OP:

It was #2.  The babel syntax `{ Routes, location: req.url }` expanded the object to have a key of `Routes`, and `match()` expects the key to be `routes`.  This can be fixed by either making it

```
import routes from './views/routes';
...
{ routes, location: req.url }
```

as suggested, or

```
import Routes from './views/routes';
...
{ routes: Routes, location: req.url }
```

Comment: Would you post your call to match()?  In my code, Routes isn't a key; it's an object, which looked weird to me, but somehow it parses in Babel.  I left it as-is because that's how it was in the docs.

Comment: I've made those three changes, but get the same result.

Comment: Scratch that.  I had made another change that prevented it from working.  The issue was #2.  The object-expansion syntax caused the variable name 'Routes' to become the key, like you said, and `match()` was expecting the key to be lowercase.